# Running Ubuntu 20.04.3 as dual boot shows problems with USB 2 ports and trying to install it using only PS/2 keyboard stuck the installer at updates

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, mouse, gigabyte

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I created [a bootable Ubuntu USB stick](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview)

I created 50GB partition for that.

My motherboard is: `Gigabyte 990XA-UD3`, the USB flash drive with the Ubuntu is connected to USB 3 port.

In the BIOS, I change in the Boot Option Priorities that the Boot Option #1 is `UEFI:    USB` and Boot Option #2 is `Windows Boot Manager`, when I restart the PC, I got a screen with the following options:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

In my PC, I have 512GB SSD with Windows 10 installed on it, and two old HDDs, one with size of 500GB and the other one with size of 1TB. My previous Windows 7 is installed on one of them, I just keep them as additional storage.

After I choose `Ubuntu`  from the options, I got some `device descriptor read/64, error -32` lines.

The first line is `unsupported SPROM revisions: 11`.

Then, the Ubuntu OS welcome window shows up and I choose the Try Ubuntu after that I choose the Install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS from the search to install it. In the stage of `Updates and other software` I choose `Normal installation` and `Download updates while installing Ubuntu` and `Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats`

Couple seconds after I choose Continue the whole system got stuck.

Beforehand, I tried to find a solution to why my mouse does not respond when I move it, I work with tutorial that said that I need to edit: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and change one the lines to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nomux i8024.noloop"`
but when I try to run `sudo update-grub` I get an error. `error:failed to get canonical path of /cow`
After trying several approaches to that problem with no success, I left it for now and I used only the keyboard to install Ubuntu.

As I explained, the system got stuck so after searching for solution, I found this: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-20-04-installer-stuck-at-updates/

I located the partition where Windows is installed but the using Shift+F10 not open up the options to choose `Unmount`

The partition is `/dev/sdb4`

After searching about some of the lines that appeared like:
`USB device not accepting address` or `device descriptor read/64, error -32`

I found that Gigabyte motherboards have some issues with 64 bit kernel and after that I found this: [USB ports not working on Gigabyte 990XA-UD3 (except USB 3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220087/usb-ports-not-working-on-gigabyte-990xa-ud3-except-usb-3)

So, I enabled `XHCI/ECHI`, still got the same problems.

After that, I connected the mouse to USB 3 port and now its working but still when I try to install Ubuntu, it is getting stuck at the same stage.

Right clicking on `/dev/sdb4` partition in `GParted` don't show the `Unmount` option and the `Mount` option is grayed out.

I also tried to launch `Ubuntu (safe graphics)` instead, got the same problem.

How do I fix these problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of the ISO download? And did you verify the integrity of the flash to USB?  Does the installation media pass integrity checks?

Comment: this guy had to enable IOMMU and edit the grub.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/usb-ports-not-working-on-gigabyte-990xa-ud3-4175671928/

Comment: Your motherboard doesn’t have any USB3.x ports as it was manufactured 10 years ago. Do you have a USB card in one of the expansion slots? If you have Nvidia graphics, you may need to set the `nomodeset` boot option 

Comment: @Nmath I downloaded a new ISO file and I get `ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso: OK`  but how do I check the integrity of the flash to USB and the integrity check of he installation media? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMantion I tried also to enable IOMMU but when I try to edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by running `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` it opens a new file with no content in it. 
In the file /etc/default/grub I changed the line to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet iommu=soft quiet splash"` saved and rebooted.
But when I run `sudo update-grub` I get the same error of  `error:failed to get canonical path of /cow`

Comment: @matigo No, I have an AMD Radeon  GPU in my primary 16X expansion slot and ASUS PCI-E Wi-Fi card on other expansion slot.

Comment: @Nmath The part of the installation worked with the new ISO that I verified it before.
Thanks.